# LibGDX создать jar файл проекта (Intellijidea, Gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, jar, libgdx

Хочется упаковать небольшой проект, сгенерированный через ***LibJDX-setup.jar***, в **его собственный jar-файл**, который можно переносить и запускать из разных папок.

Упражнения с `core/build.gradle` выдавали ошибку компиляции, подробности ниже. В `desktop/` есть два предустановленных манифеста: `desktop\build\dist\MANIFEST.MF, desktop\build\jar\MANIFEST.MF`.

В них только :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Main-Class: com.game.DesktopLauncher
```

Так код компилируется и запускается, но результата (jar файла) нет

```
task dist(type: Jar) {
duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    attributes 'Destination-Dir': project.ext.gameJarDir //объект типа File. Вот как атрибут правильно назвать?

}
dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
with jar
```

}

Была попытка подстроить `core/build.gradle` по примеру из разных Gradle-guides:

- https://spring-projects.ru/guides/gradle/
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html

Не компилируется.

> Ошибка Could not find method (имя)___ for arguments или похожие.

Синтаксис для gradle везде немного отличается

Comment: *В desktop/build.gradle по логике нужно просто добавить правильные атрибуты?*

Comment: Документация предлагает воспользоваться утилитой  packr.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! нагуглила про packr, буду пробовать. Буду очень признательна, если кинете ссылочку на документацию

Comment: Под документацией имел ввиду статью в Вики на оф.сайте: https://libgdx.com/wiki/deployment/bundling-a-jre, это инструмент команды LibGDX. Документацию по самому Packr можно найти в репозитории на гитхабе: https://github.com/libgdx/packr